# Comprehensive list of Czech words in ubuntu /usr/share/dict

Tags: language-support, dictionary

I need a comprehensive list of Czech words. By comprehensive, I mean a list (one word per line) that has more than 70K words at least covered. Is there a way to add Czech to /usr/share/dict? I cannot find any resources on ubuntu package installer (other languages are covered but not Czech) and Google was not helpful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Czech dictionary for myspell (*myspell-cs*) and Czech dictionary for GNU Aspell (*aspell-cs*) can be installed from the default repositories in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To install one or the other Czech dictionary package run either `sudo apt install myspell-cs` or `sudo apt install aspell-cs`

There is a list of 166,566 Czech words at: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/titoBouzout/Dictionaries/master/Czech.dic. This list contains words only and does not include the definitions of the words in the list.

Comment: Do you know any list for german as well?

Comment: In the Ubuntu Software Center there are four packages for German: *aspell-de*, *hunspell-de-de* (core version), *hunspell-de-de-frami* (enhanced version) and *myspell-de-de* . The *hunspell-de-de-frami* package contains a enhanced version with some words missing in the base dictionary or not (yet) belonging to the "core" German words. *myspell-de-de* is particularly useful because the myspell spellchecker is currently used within the Mozilla spellchecker, so it can be used for spellchecking in Firefox.

Comment: @user3639557: As regards Czech, I see both myspell-cs and aspell-cs in the Ubuntu archive.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson You deserve the accept vote for answering this question and also for contributing code to language-selector. I wish I could give you my answer's upvotes too. It would certainly be fair. Unfortunately I can't even get out of your way by deleting my second-rate answer, because it has already been accepted. Maybe there's some way I can wriggle out of this unpleasant situation.

Comment: @karel: No problem; I'm not here for the reputation score. ;) With your answer and my comment the OPs question has been reasonably covered. Please feel free to edit the question, and include the packages in the archive, so that info gets better highlighted.

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/tvondra/ispell_czech

Answer (score 1):

I needed to grep specific words in whole Czech dictionary too and used `aspell` containing 3.1M czech words.

```
$apt install aspell aspell-cs
$aspell -d cs dump master | aspell -l cs expand | wc -l
3141344
$aspell -d cs dump master | aspell -l cs expand | egrep ".{30,}" | wc -l
110
```

This shows total count of words longer 30+ characters. You can play with different grep pattern to find missing words in crosswords :-)

**Source:** https://superuser.com/questions/137957/how-to-convert-aspell-dictionary-to-simple-list-of-words